# Given an array of hashes modify each one to include a key value combination of another hash

Tags: ruby

Example 1:

```
array_of_hashes = [{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30}, {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35}]

metadata_hash = {"likes"=>["apples", "oranges"], "dislikes"=>["cold"]}
```

How would you get to this output:

```
[{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold"},
 {"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold"},
 {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold"},
 {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold"}]
```

Example 2:

```
array_of_hashes = [{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30}, {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35}]
metadata_hash = {"likes"=>["apples", "oranges"], "dislikes"=>["cold"], "courses"=>["science", "history"]}
```

Expected Output:

```
[{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
 {"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"},
 {"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"}
 {"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"},
 {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
 {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"},
 {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"}
 {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"}]
```

Comment: The question is ambiguous because the values in `metadata_hash` (arrays) are inconsistent in size. It is not clear, for example, whether that hash could be `{"likes"=>["apples", "oranges"], "dislikes"=>["cold"], "indifferents"=>["dog", "cat", "pig]}` and if if could, what result would be desired. That is the problem with casting a question in terms of a single example. Examples are meant for illustration, after the question has been stated unambiguously in words.

Comment: @CarySwoveland you're correct the `metadata_hash` could be of any size - but it would always retain the same structure e.g. `{ key: [array of elements], key: [array of elements], key: [array of elements] }`

Comment: @CarySwoveland have updated the question with a further example

Comment: I see. The update to the example clarifies what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = [{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30}, {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35}]

meta_hash = {"likes"=>["apples", "oranges"], "dislikes"=>["cold"],
             "courses"=>["science", "history"]}
```

---

You can compute the desired result as follows.

```
keys, (first_value, *rest_of_values) = metadata_hash.to_a.transpose
  #=> [["likes", "dislikes", "courses"], [["apples", "oranges"],
       ["cold"], ["science", "history"]]]
```

Ergo,

```
keys
  #=> ["likes", "dislikes", "courses"]
first_value
  #=> ["apples", "oranges"]
rest_of_values = ["cold"], ["science", "history"]]
```

```
a = first_value.product(*rest_of_values).map { |arr| keys.zip(arr).to_h }
  #=> [{"likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
  #    {"likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"},
  #    {"likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
  #    {"likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"}]
```

```
array_of_hashes.flat_map { |h| a.map { |g| h.merge(g) }}
  #=> [{"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
  #    {"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"},
  #    {"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
  #    {"name"=>"bob", "age"=>30, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"},
  #    {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
  #    {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"apples", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"},
  #    {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"science"},
  #    {"name"=>"bart", "age"=>35, "likes"=>"oranges", "dislikes"=>"cold", "courses"=>"history"}]
```

---

The first step in the calculation of `a` is the following.

```
first_value.product(*rest_of_values)
  #=> [["apples", "cold", "science"], ["apples", "cold", "history"],
  #    ["oranges", "cold", "science"], ["oranges", "cold", "history"]]
```

See [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product), [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge). [Array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) was employed in the calculation of `keys`, `first_value` and  `rest_of_values`. See this [article](https://riptutorial.com/ruby/example/8798/decomposition) (for example) for more information on that subject.